# array data populating issues with Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a array of data which was generated due to some Actions in my previous actions

On submitting that page, Control will be redirecting to the second page,
IN the second page, I need to populate the array data into the Tables
( I want to use Javascript to populate this, No other means)

Problems which i am facing now

1) I cant read the Java array in the Java script ? (I am not sure how to pass the Java array to Javascript function)

2) Thought of implementing the Java script objects similar to the java objects, but there will be lot of over head

Can any one help me to over come this situation

I am using the BTT framework which is similar to Struts, for Javascript I am not using any frameworks

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would really help if you told us what web framework you were using, and were clearer about this "array of data" - this is client side, server-side?

Comment: how far you are able to proceed? are you able to post JS Array to server?

Comment: @Narendra, that is one more difficulty that I may face if I use the Javascript, it will be difficult to post to the server

Answer (score 0):

JSON would be a format to make the java-array accessible in javascript.
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/blob/master/JSONStringer.java

Answer (score 0):

too broad to answer, since specifics are missing. here are some generic steps.

1. Collect your stuff in JavaScript array
2. Have a hidden form field
3. while posting to server, set the value of hidden field to your array (in string format)
4. Read the hidden field content in server (posted form data)
5. Parse them (**JSON** is appropriate here)
6. Use them while preparing next page content as JS Array